# Best way of automatically reconnect python socket after "connection reset by peer"?

Tags: python, sockets, nohup

I am making a python script that retrieves temperature information from a sensor via socket and prints it in an output file. The script runs in a debian environment and was meant to run continuously and independent from terminal via

```
nohup ./python_script.py &>output_file.out &
```

The server, however, disconnects after a few hours and by looking at the .out file i am getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "./python_script.py", line 29, in <module>   
    counter=0   
OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected
```

The script is intended to reconnect if any error occurs by use of

```
try:   
except:
```

The complete script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from My_Classes import Equipment, Ethernet_Switch
from datetime import date, datetime
import time, socket

def nice_format(unformatted):
    if len(unformatted)==1:
        unformatted="0"+unformatted

server="Ethernet_Switch_IP"
rport = Ethernet_Equipment_Port
eki = Ethernet_Switch(server)
boc = Equipment(port=rport,connec=eki,timeout=1)
start_time = time.time()
counter=0
while time.time()-start_time<345600:
    try:
        temperature=boc.get_current_temperature()
        hour=str(datetime.now().hour)
        minute=str(datetime.now().minute)
        nice_format(hour)
        nice_format(minute)
        print("Day: "+str(date.today())+"    Time: "+hour+":"+minute+"\tTemperature [°C]: "+str(temperature)+"\t"+str(time.time())+"\n")
    except:
        counter=counter+1
    if counter==3:
        print("Trying to reconnect")
        counter=0
        boc.soc.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
        boc.soc.close()
        boc.soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        boc.soc.connect((server,rport))
    time.sleep(3)
```

The soc. property of the boc object is a socket. I tested disconnection and connecting it via the same methods used in this script and it worked.

I cannot understand why

```
counter=0
```

would generate an error. Am i doing something wrong? Is there a better way of making this script "disconenction proof"? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you just try to remove boc.soc.shutdown?

Comment: You should have your connect and reconnect logic in the same place which in this case is apparently inside the `boc` object. Splitting it out like this is very confusing. Best to just augment the `get_current_temperature()` function with reconnect logic.

Comment: @seven_seas You mean to use just boc.soc.close()? The shutdown and close methods are intended to disconnect the socket for further reconnection with boc.soc.connect(). This was meant to not interrupt the script in case of connection reset by peer and keep trying to reconnect.

Comment: @vaizki thanks for the suggestion. Will do. Would creating a boc.disconnect_socket() and a boc.reconnect_socket() method be a bad way of doing it? Also, it might be a little hard to test since the error just comes up randomly after some hours of execution. I will update if new errors occur or if the script manages to survive for one day and one night.